# Cut a file in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, filemanager

When copy, cutting and pasting a file. In other OS there is a visual feedback when you cut a file. Is it possible to customize that in FileManager PCManFM. Or is there another file manager that you would recommend that has that feature.

Comment: What did you mean? A progressbar? Lubuntu has already somthing like this -> http://250kb.de/u/140530/p/AFbgUSSCJ6GX.png (testet on 14.04)